# Fixed Check box when text changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a check box with text and check box is aligned at right side of its text.
The text of check box has string id and and the text changes when language is changed.
When length of text is increased or decreased,  the check box also moves with the text.
Is there any way to fix the check box at right side and to move text to the left when its length is increased or decreased.

[image]

Eg:
"**[]**" be my text box and its text is "**abcd**". Check box is aligned to the right side of text.
   **abcd[]** //If I change text to "abcdefgh"
     **abcdefgh[]** //This is how it looks, and I want it to look like given below,
 **abcdefgh[]** //Check boxes in same vertical position and text moves to left.
*Thanks for reading.*
**Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: Can you add an image for both examples?

Comment: Please add a picture to your question, it will make it easier to understand what you mean.

Comment: Have you tried to anchor your CheckBoxes `Top/Right` instead of `Top/Left`?